# CoreOS fleetctl list-machines not showing 3 machines

Tags: digital-ocean, coreos

I am following the DigitalOcean tutorial on CoreOS (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-flexible-services-for-a-coreos-cluster-with-fleet-unit-files).  When I do a fleetctl list-machines command on node 1 and node 2, I am not able to see all the 3 machines listed but just one for it's own node.  The following is what I see:

```
core@coreos-1 ~ $ fleetctl list-machines
MACHINE     IP      METADATA
XXXX... 10.abc.de.fgh   -
```

I logged onto my 3rd node and noticed that when I do a fleetctl list-machines I get the following error:

```
core@coreos-3 ~ $ fleetctl list-machines
Error retrieving list of active machines: googleapi: Error 503: fleet server unable to communicate with etc
```

What should I do to find out what is the problem and how to resolve this?  I have tried rebooting and other things mentioned but nothing is helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened was that I had a etcd dependencies in my unit file where I had such as following:

```
# Dependency ordering
After=etcd.service
```

I think I needed etcd2 instead.

So I did the following as directed:

```
sudo systemctl stop fleet.service fleet.socket etcd
sudo systemctl start etcd2
sudo systemctl reset-failed
```

I had to clean up on the instance that had the file when I queried for it:

```
core@coreos1 ~ $ etcdctl ls /_coreos.com/fleet/job
/_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache.1.service
/_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache@.service
/_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache@80.service
/_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache@9999.service
/_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache-discovery.1.service
/_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache-discovery@.service
/_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache-discovery@80.service
/_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache-discovery@9999.service
```

by issuing

```
etcdctl ls /_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache.1.service
etcdctl rm --recursive /_coreos.com/fleet/job/apache-discovery.1.service
```

Then I started fleet

```
sudo systemctl start fleet
```

And when I did a fleetctl list-machines again it showed all my instances connected.